# Core data -[Decodable.Address initWithCoder:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, unrecognized-selector, transformable

I have implemented JSON parsing with swift **Codable** and storing it with **Coredata** . My Code works fine while storing the JSON and fetching entities which don't have "transformable" attribute. But fetch entity fails and crashes with below log in case where any of it attribute is transformable. I need to keep transformable attribute in case of Custom Objects. Have a look at below core data model classes and fetch request for my implementation. 
Console log:

```
-[Decodable.Address initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to 
instance 0x600000464c40

2018-06-14 11:26:52.768499+0530 Decodable[7870:2988621] [error] error: 
  exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600000381fb0> 
  , -[Decodable.Address initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to 
  instance 0x600000464c40 with userInfo of (null)

CoreData: error: exception handling request: 
  <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x600000381fb0> , -[Decodable.Address 
  initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000464c40 
  with userInfo of (null)

2018-06-14 11:26:52.777634+0530 Decodable[7870:2988621] *** 
  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
  'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Decodable.Address 
  initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
  0x600000464c40'
```

ViewController.swift

```
 let request = NSFetchRequest<Clinic>(entityName: "Clinic")
 request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = true

    do
    {
   managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

   let result = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)//***Crashes!!
    }
    catch
    {
        print("no record found")
    }
```

Clinic+CoreDataClass.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

public class Clinic: NSManagedObject, NSCoding {


public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

    aCoder.encode(address, forKey: ClinicCodingKeys.address.rawValue)
  // also encode other class attributes
}

public required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    guard let contextUserInfoKey = CodingUserInfoKey.context,
        let managedObjectContext = 
appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext as? 
NSManagedObjectContext,
        let entityDescription = 
NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName:"Clinic", in: 
managedObjectContext) else {  fatalError()  }
    self.init(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: 
appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)

    self.address = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: 
ClinicCodingKeys.address.rawValue) as? Address
 //*** Also decode other attributes
}

public override func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: ClinicCodingKeys.self)

    try container.encode(remoteid , forKey: .remoteid)
    try container.encode(landline ?? "" , forKey: .landline)
    try container.encode(name ?? "", forKey: .name)
    try container.encode(address , forKey: .address)
    try container.encode(mobile ?? "", forKey: .mobile)
    try container.encode(email ?? "", forKey: .email)
}


public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

    guard let contextUserInfoKey = CodingUserInfoKey.context,
        let managedObjectContext = 
    decoder.userInfo[contextUserInfoKey] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
        let entity = 
    NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName:"Clinic", in: 
    managedObjectContext) else {  fatalError()  }

    self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ClinicCodingKeys.self)

    remoteid = try values.decode(Int16.self, forKey: .remoteid)
    landline = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .landline)
    name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    address = try values.decode(Address.self, forKey: .address)
    mobile = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .mobile)
    email = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)
}
}
```

Clinic+CoreDataProperties.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Clinic: Codable {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Clinic> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Clinic>(entityName: "Clinic")
}

@NSManaged public var remoteid: Int16
@NSManaged public var landline: String?
@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var address: Address?//***** Transformable attribute 
    //for core data model class Address
@NSManaged public var mobile: String?
@NSManaged public var email: String?

enum ClinicCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case remoteid = "_id"
    case landline
    case name
    case address
    case mobile
    case email
}
}
```

Address+CoreDataClass.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


public class Address: NSManagedObject {


public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(address ?? "" , forKey: .address)
    try container.encode(area ?? "" , forKey: .area)
    try container.encode(postalcode ?? "" , forKey: .postalcode)
    try container.encode(city ?? "" , forKey: .city)
    try container.encode(state ?? "" , forKey: .state)
    try container.encode(country ?? "" , forKey: .country)
    try container.encode(lat ?? "" , forKey: .lat)
    try container.encode(lng ?? "" , forKey: .lng)
}

public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

    guard let contextUserInfoKey = CodingUserInfoKey.context,
        let managedObjectContext = 
decoder.userInfo[contextUserInfoKey] as? NSManagedObjectContext,
        let entity = 
NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName:"Address", in: 
managedObjectContext) else {  fatalError()  }

    self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: managedObjectContext)
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    address = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .address)
    area = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .area)
    postalcode = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .postalcode)
    city = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .city)
    state = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .state)
    country = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .country)
    lat = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .lat)
    lng = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .lng)

}
}
```

Address+CoreDataProperties.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Address : Codable{

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Address> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Address>(entityName: "Address")
}

@NSManaged public var address: String?
@NSManaged public var area: String?
@NSManaged public var postalcode: String?
@NSManaged public var city: String?
@NSManaged public var state: String?
@NSManaged public var country: String?
@NSManaged public var lat: String?
@NSManaged public var lng: String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
{
    case address
    case area
    case postalcode = "postal_code"
    case city
    case state
    case country
    case lat
    case lng
}
}
```

I have tried implementing initWithCoder: in Clinic+CoreDataClass.swift but it gives error - Cannot invoke initWith(entity: insertInto:). And I need to implement initwith(entity: insertinto:)

Comment: can you also post the implementation for Address?

Comment: @RohanBhale added the code of Model class "Address".

Comment: also implement NSCoding protocol here. these unrecognised selectors error belong missing methods of the NSCoding protocol

Comment: But Codable is what we got for replacing old NSCoding (check [https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/migrating-to-codable-from-nscoding-ddc2585f28a4]). I have Implemented Codable . So why NSCoding protocols are needed. This same implementation works fine when there's no transformable attribute in model class/Entity. There's no NSCoding protocol implemented there. But when Custom objects are passed as type for attribute(here "Address" in Clinic+CoreDataProperties.swift), it crashes.

Comment: Also when I conform to NSCoding , and put methods func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) . It gives error (same error as I stated on last line in question.)

Comment: Codable is a Swift defined stuff. CoreData is developed using objc runtime. Codable is fine for parsing stuff. In order to save data though you need to use NSCoding protocol. If you look closely even the method definitions are different for encoding and decoding

Comment: @RohanBhale Thanks a lot, for pointing  out Codable and Core data difference. For all others, as said, "Codable" doesnt help decode/encode "transformable" attribute. For that I implemented Codable along with NSCoding. Means Codable is good for parsing json and basic data types other than transformable. I had to conform to "NSCoding" in my CoreData model classes to decode encode and fetch "transformable" types properly. Have updated the Qn. with Solution that worked for me. Hope Apple provides something in next swift releases to support "transformable", so that Codable can replace NSCoding.

Comment: @Shirish Thanks It's working!! After Adding NSCoding

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching it wrongly `NSFetchRequest<Clinic>(entityName: "Clinic")` and you are not checking entity records before saving into result variable.

```
  let request = NSFetchRequest<Clinic>(entityName: "Clinic")
     request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = true

        do
        {
       managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

       let result = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)//***Crashes!!
        }
        catch
        {
            print("no record found")
        }
```

Replace your code with `fetchData()` function and make sure Entity name is same.

```
func fetchData()   {
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Clinic")
            do{
                 let records = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

                if let records = records as? [NSManagedObject]{
                    if !records.isEmpty{
                        var result:[NSManagedObject] = records
                        print("coreData result : \(records)")
                    }else{
                       print("No record in Clinic entity")
                    }

                }

            }catch{
                print("Error")
            }
        }
```

Comment: After replacing with your code for "fetch", still crashes with same logs on same line context.fetch(fetchRequest).

Comment: See at top in Question. I get the same logs as I have put in question.

Comment: @Shirish Make sure Clinic is entity name and saving data in core data correctly.I am thinking that Issue may be with entity name.

Comment: Yes, entity with name "Clinic" exists and is getting saved perfectly. Other entities which don't have a attribute of type "transformable" work fine while fetching. Here Clinic(as well as other entities!) entity which has attribute of type "transformable" ,crash for fetching. For transformable entity address I have set type "Address"(another model class) .

Comment: @Shirish I am also facing same crash did you got solution..?

Comment: @salmansiddiqui I have mentioned the problem & solution with Codable implementation in conversation with Rohan . Read  those last few comments. For transformable attributes you have to conform to NSCoding and implement its methods to get it working. See I have update it for Clinic class in question.